# Find the smallest number who gives remainders $75,60,105$ when divided by $90,75,120$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Which is the least number when divided by $90,75,120$ leaves remainder $75,60,105$ respectively? How should approach this question

Comment: Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem and all possible modular information you can get by breaking these numbers into prime factors. E.g your number should be odd, $3$ mod $9$, $10$ mod $25$, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

The Chinese Remainder Theorem gives a systematic way to solve such problems.

For this particular problem, there is a shortcut.
We want

$
x \equiv \ 75 \bmod 90
\\
x \equiv \ 60 \bmod 75
\\
x \equiv 105 \bmod 120
$

or, equivalently,

$
x+15 \equiv 0 \bmod 90
\\
x+15 \equiv 0 \bmod 75
\\
x+15 \equiv 0 \bmod 120
$

Therefore, $x+15$ is a common multiple of $90,75,120$ and so is a multiple of $lcm(90,75,120)=1800$.